# Optimization problem, minimal speed of point

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

What is the minimal speed of a point moving according to this law:$$S(t)=t^3+3t+1$$ $[m], t-[s]$
Will I get the answer by finding the global minimum of this function? Or is it about finding a point where function declines the most? I'm lost

Comment: What does $S(t)$ represent here? Speed? Position?

Comment: Does $t$ stand for time?

Comment: Yes t stands for time in seconds

Comment: Does $S(t)$ represent position?

Comment: Be careful: in general “speed” is not the same thing as “velocity,” although happily in this case the velocity is always positive.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the displacement of the particle, we have:
$$V(t)=S'(t)=3t^2+3$$
Which is minimal where $t=0$ giving a speed of 3.

If this is the speed of the particle, the speed is minimal at $t=0$ giving a speed of 1.